# Python flask logging: two different formats, but want one format

Tags: python, flask, logging

I am working on a REST API using Flask.

The API is currently divided across two Python 3.6 modules: update.py and vmware_exporters_support.py.

update.py logs the way I want.  vmware_exporters_support.py does not log the way I want. I want vmware_exporters_support.py to use update.py's logging format *without* logging things twice.

In update.py, the logging is set up with:

```
from flask.logging import create_logger
app = Flask('collector_api')
logger = create_logger(app)    
import vmware_exporters_support
```

And create_logger, which is part of Flask, is at
https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1.1.x/src/flask/logging.py

Then in vmware_exporters_support.py I'm setting up logging with:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

It seems like this should just get the root logger from update.py, but I'm not sure it does really considering how differently it's acting.

An illustrative log snippet looks like:

```
[2021-01-21 12:12:29,810] INFO in update: Writing container yaml /data/vmware-exporter/vmware_exporter_1
2021-01-21.12:12:29  INFO     Writing container yaml /data/vmware-exporter/vmware_exporter_1
```

The [2021-01-21 12:12:29,810] (with the square brackets) is coming from update.py, and the 2021-01-21.12:12:29 (without the square brackets) is coming from vmware_exporters_support.py

What do I need to do to get vmware_exporters_support.py to use the same logging format as update.py?

BTW, update.py is the `__main__`, not vmware_exporters_support.py.

And I'm using Flask 1.1.2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> The main reason - you have 2 different loggers

[create_logger()](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1.1.x/src/flask/logging.py#L87) using `app.name` for logger name(`collector_api`). But in `vmware_exporters_support.py` you created `RootLogger`(`logger = logging.getLogger()`). Therefore loggers may have different handlers and formatters. Here is an example how it works in your case:

```
import logging

logger1 = logging.getLogger('collector_api')
logger1.propagate = False
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fm = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(fm)
logger1.addHandler(ch)
# logger2 without handler and formatter...
logger2 = logging.getLogger()
logger2.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# uncomment later
# for h in logger1.handlers:
#     logger2.addHandler(h)

logger1.info('first')
logger2.info('second')
```

run script. you will see only 1 message: `2021-01-25 11:11:19,241 - collector_api - INFO - first`

now try to uncomment `for h in logger1.handlers:...`. You'll see 2 messages:

```
2021-01-25 11:13:53,593 - collector_api - INFO - first
2021-01-25 11:13:53,593 - root - INFO - second
```

So you need to use 1 logger or use the same handlers and formatters for 2 loggers.